Specific dimen loses effect in tabular
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline
  A \hbox{\vrule height 8.4pt depth 3.6pt width 1pt} &
  A \hbox{\vrule height\ht\strutbox depth\dp\strutbox width 1pt} &
  A \hbox{\vrule height .7\baselineskip depth .3\baselineskip width 1pt} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
A \hbox{\vrule height 8.4pt depth 3.6pt width 1pt}
A \hbox{\vrule height\ht\strutbox depth\dp\strutbox width 1pt}
A \vrule height .7\baselineskip depth .3\baselineskip width 1pt

\end{document}

The three vrules in the tabular are in fact the same with respect to their sizes. According to the TeXbook, .7\baselineskip and .3\baselineskip are both legitimate ⟨dimen⟩s since

.7 & .3 ∈ ⟨decimal constant⟩ ⊂ ⟨factor⟩
\baselineskip ∈ ⟨glue parameter⟩ ⊂ ⟨internal glue⟩ ⊂ ⟨internal unit⟩ ⊂ ⟨unit of measure⟩

Result of the MWE:

Outside the tabular environment, they all behave as expected. While in the tabular, the third dimen specification loses effect. What is the reason behind this?

\baselineskip is 0pt in tabular

@DavidCarlisle Thank you

tabular sets \baselineskip to 0pt (related to ensuring vertical rules from | touch in each row). It is locally set back by \@arrayparboxrestore in p columns.
If you need to access the standard baselineskip within the body of a table then it is available in \normalbaselineskip  but any standard latex interface to an area that uses baseline spacing would have reset \baselineskip (so inside any minipage, \parbox, p columns etc, \baselineskip is non zero).
